# Creating @SCOPE_NAME in azure artifacts for NPM

Tags: azure, azure-artifacts, .npmrc

[**In this link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/scopes?view=azure-devops), Microsoft explained How to create **@Scope_Name**, but I did not understand Where to create **@Scope_Name**.

How can I create it?

Thanks in advance

Any help would be appreciated